# How do I show changes in a element which is common among other routes when a certain other Route is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For Example, in the website I'm making the navbar has some number of options which the user can select from like Home, News, Shop etc. Now when I am in Home page I want a bottom-border under the Home in Navbar and similarly for other states.
The App.js looks something like this

```
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
                <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
                <Route path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```

Currently what I have done is, I have made a class called current with the css I want it to have and added it to the Home Link. But I don't think is going to work.
I have just started to learn React so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you clarify more precisely what you trying to do? It's a bit unclear (*to me*) what "want a bottom-border under the Home in Navbar and similarly for other states" means. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear about my question. The "want a bottom-border under the Home in Navbar and similarly for other states" meant that I wanted an indicator on the Navbar to show user as to what page he/she is on. So the bottom border is just an indicator on the navbar. It being under the home section meant that currently user is on Home and similarly for others. Using `useLocation`, I have been able to figure out how to add css dynamically to the element I want. Thank You

Comment: I see. Please share all relevant component code in your question so we can see what  it is trying to do. It seems you could use a `NavLink` component and provide an active styling for the currently active link. Regarding your comment in answer below, RRDv6 routes/links no longer take an `exact` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do inside **`Navbar`** is to use `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom` and check whether it is matching with the path you are passing to routes and with the help of CSS add class to the corresponding Nav option. Also you are not using `exact` option for routes and without that `/news` and `/shops` will also match with `/` in the first case and never render the appropriate component instead it will always be `Main` component that will gets rendered